# Why does consumer read all messages from Kafka topic after restart?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I use confluent .net client.
Subscriber always reads all messages from Kafka topic after restarting(subscriber service restarting).
How to commit offset that consumer already achieved and read from it?
Maybe some consumer configuration can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- enable auto commit by setting the consumer properties `EnableAutoCommit = true` (the messages are getting committed after a configurable time, typically 5 seconds), or
- manually commit the fetched offsets by `consumer.Commit(consumeResult)`.

An example for the manual commits is shown on [GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Consumer/Program.cs).

Comment: EnableAutoCommit = true was setted and group name is constant. But it is not 5 seconds, it is dozen of hours. Probably some additional settings setted on broker or on another place

Comment: You can check the other ConsumerProducer `auto.commit.interval.ms` which is documented [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto.commit.interval.ms)

Answer (score 3):

This is just a wild guess, but how do you declare the consumer's group id?
I've seen some examples using this kind of random assignation:

```
     ["group.id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
```

If you declare a new/random `group.id` each time you launch the consumers, that would lead to the registration of a new consumer group on each execution, which involves `auto.offset.reset` kicking in.

If this property is set to "`earliest`", then every time you launch your consumers (assuming they have a different group.id each time), they will start from the first avaliable offset, as in your case, reading all the messages again from the beginning.

If this property is set to "`latest`", and your producers are currently not sending any messages, you won't be able to read anything, which could create some confusion.

Try setting a fixed `group.id`: start consuming, stop the process while messages are still avaliable on the broker, and launch the consumer again, without changing the last `group.id`.

This time, as the consumer group is already registered, `auto.offset.reset` will be ignored and the starting position would be defined by your commited offsets, which are by default stored on a special topic called `__consumer_offsets`.